# Redirect URI with Client Credential Flow

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am looking into using MSAL and client credential flow, however, there is one thing I don't fully understand.

In the example provided by Microsoft:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/blob/master/daemon-console/Program.cs

The following code is used to get an access token:

```
var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(_clientSecret);
var app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(_clientId, _authority, "https://daemon", clientCredentials, null, new TokenCache());
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);
```

Whats with the redirectUri in this case?

I have tried different values as the redirectUri and it seems to work either way... but if I add a relative path or null it fails to obtain a token. What is this value supposed to be?

For a console application it makes little sense to listen on an URL, however, the documentation for ConfidentialClientApplication says that it is required.

Comment: RedirectURI is supposed to provide a URL for web application where STS (in this case AzureAD) can call back with token.. As you correctly suspect this value will not matter for Client Credential Grant.. I "guess" (but not sure) this concept of redirect URI stems from application type being web application.. Azure AD only has web app or native app types.. For console app/daemon - which can act as a confidential client and use client secrets you will choose web application type (even though it's counter intuitive and documentation for this sample and other places will mention the same)

Comment: It seems odd to me as on-behalf-of doesnt seem to need a redirectUri either and if this is the case then I dont see a single use for redirectUri in the ConfidentialClientApplication contructor. Furthermore, when adding certain values to this redirectUri the acquireToken will fail so there is some thing it will trigger on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To request access token with client credential flow , app will send HTTP POST token request to Azure AD's token endpoint with app's credential ,  AAD will return access token in response , redirect url is not need in this scenario . According to source code , the redirect url is not used also:

```
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenForClientCommonAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes, bool forceRefresh, ApiEvent.ApiIds apiId, bool sendCertificate)
{
    Authority authority = Instance.Authority.CreateAuthority(ServiceBundle, Authority, ValidateAuthority);
    AuthenticationRequestParameters parameters = CreateRequestParameters(authority, scopes, null,
        AppTokenCache);
    parameters.IsClientCredentialRequest = true;
    parameters.SendCertificate = sendCertificate;
    var handler = new ClientCredentialRequest(
        ServiceBundle,
        parameters,
        apiId,
        forceRefresh);

    return await handler.RunAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

But you should  provide a valid url when initializing the `ConfidentialClientApplication` at this point .

Comment: Tl:DR; the constructor is dumb and requires a URL when it will not require one with client credentials.

Comment: Interesting, however, it will fail to AcquireToken if you do supply a relative url (e.g. "/signin-oidc") or a null, so its used for something...